# How to set contextual value object in Symfony?

Tags: php, design-patterns, symfony

I extract some information from **master request** using a listener on `kernel.request`. I want to information to be available to all controller and maybe other listeners, services.

Since it is a value object `UserContext` I don't want to make it into a service.

What is the best way/pattern for setting this contextual value object so it is available everywhere?

My current idea is to set it to `$request` object:

```
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) {
        return;
    }

    $request = $event->getRequest();

    $userContext = $this->userContextFactory->createFromRequest($request);

    $request->attributes->set('_user_context', $userContext);
}
```

Another idea, define a helper service, which can be used/injected to other services:

```
class UserContextHelper
{
    ...

    public function getUserContext()
    {
        $masterRequest = $this->requestStack->getMasterRequest();
        return $this
                 ->userContextFactory
                 ->createFromRequest($masterRequest);

}
```

Comment: Yep.  Setting it in the request is exactly what I do so it must be right:)  BTW, Event::isMasterRequest can simplify your guard.

Comment: @Cerad But isn't that too obscure? It's also a whole class, not just some key-string pair lying in the param bag. Wouldn't it be better to make `UserContextHelper` that uses `RequestStack` to deduce `UserContext` from `$masterRequest` and always return it? I could also inject this service into other services, in service configuration.

Comment: As long as you are certain that the consumers of UserContext don't attempt to use it before the request is actually being processed then the UserContextHelper (aka factory?) is fine.  The problem is that your consumer service might try calling getUserContext before the user is even available.  Especially if the consumer service itself is injected into another service.  Stuff that depends on the request can be tricky.